# Accessing a repository in AccountController through constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, constructor, controller

I am using the MVC AccountController that implements the ASP.NET Membership Provder.
I have a repository with all my database access in which I have added a Countries property that returns a list of countries. I want to add a country dropdown to the Register page so I need to be able to get this data from my repository and pass it to the View. 
I have been using contructor injection in my other controllers but I dont know how to apply this to the existing AccountController.

```
        // This constructor is used by the MVC framework to instantiate the controller using
    // the default forms authentication and membership providers.

    public AccountController()
        : this(null, null)
    {
    }

    // This constructor is not used by the MVC framework but is instead provided for ease
    // of unit testing this type. See the comments at the end of this file for more
    // information.
    public AccountController(IFormsAuthentication formsAuth, IMembershipService service)
    {
        FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
        MembershipService = service ?? new AccountMembershipService();
    }
```

Can I change the existing AccountController constructor to access my repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already registered your repository with ninject, you should be able to just add a third parameter to the constructor of the controller. I saw your earlier comment about ninject, but I'm not using NinjectModule. If you're using MVC 3, would suggest that you take a look at **nuget** (http://nuget.codeplex.com) and download the **Ninject.MVC3** packge which adds a AppStartNinjectMvc3 class to your project where you can register services with the kernel.Bind methods:

```
kernel.Bind<IThingRepository>().To<SqlThingRepository>();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can recommend using Windsor instead due to its nice implementation of *component burden*.

Answer (score 1):

Register the services in your IoC engine and then remove the default constructor.

Comment: I got it working by adding a reference as the third parameter int the defautl constructor but does this defeat teh purpose of IoC? I am using NInject so would I add this in the NinjectModule `private class PublicationServices : NinjectModule
        {
            public override void Load()
            {
               ?? What goes here ??
            }
        }`

Comment: I guess you already have your answer. But to clarify; the default c'tor is that which doesn't contain any parameters. You don't do "?? new XXX();" if you are using IoC as this defeats the purpose of IoC, that you don't "new up" things yourself.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I hadn't set up my bindings correctly either but I'm beginning to get the hang of IoC now.

Answer (score 0):

If your using MVC2 you should take a look at http://mvcstarter.codeplex.com/ it's also using Ninject. Like @Johan said you simply have to put the parameter and bind it in the global.asax.cs.

Hope it helps!